# Nested Eloquent Relation - HasOneThrough Issue

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have below setup for tables:

`Product_variant` Table

```
Product_variant -> id, name, code, image
```

`Warehouse` table

```
Warehouse -> id, name, address
```

`Product Variant Stock` table

```
Product_Variant_stock -> stock_id, warehouse_id, variant_id, stock_qty
```

Now, what i need to get information is about in which **Warehouse**, variant has been stored, when i try to access product variant information.

What i have tried in **ProductVariation** model:

```
public function warehouseName()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Warehouse::class, ProductVariantStock::class, 'warehouse_id', 'id');
}
```

Above is not working as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel hasOneThrough works like this

```
class ModelA extends Model
{
    ...
    
    public function cModel()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            ModelC::class,
            ModelB::class,
            'model_a_id', // Key on B that relates to A
            'model_c_id', // Key on C that relates to B
            'a_id',       // Key on A that relates to B
            'b_id',       // Key on B that relates to C
        );
    }
}
```

so your code will be

```
public function warehouseName()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Warehouse::class, ProductVariantStock::class, 'variant_id', 'id', 'id', 'warehouse_id');
}
```

Comment: With this, I am getting
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'warehouses.warehouse_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `warehouses`.*, `product_variation_stocks`.`variant_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `warehouses` inner join `product_variation_stocks` on `product_variation_stocks`.`stock_id` = `warehouses`.`warehouse_id` where `product_variation_stocks`.`variant_id` = 1 limit 1)". I then changed warehouse_id to id and then there is no record

Comment: i just changed the code. i hope it will work. @Gags

Comment: nope.. It worked like this
return $this->hasOneThrough(Warehouse::class, ProductVariationStock::class, 'variant_id', 'id',  'id', 'warehouse_id');

Comment: Sometimes, it is fun to work with these eloquent complex relationships :).. cheers

Comment: yes. if we understand these it is real fun.

Comment: It is not this much clear in Laravel documentation as you have explained and we did it.. Thanks